# jquery - function not defined - document and windows objects confusion

Tags: jquery, function

I´m trying to declare a simple function in jquery and call it and all the time, it´s confusing for me.

I got this error :

> resizeAllMansoryItems is not defined

How can I declare it correctly ?
This is my jQuery script :

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var resizeAllMansonryItems = function (selector_to_get_height) {
        var allItems = $('.h4a-brick');

        /*
         * Loop through the above list and execute the spanning function to
         * each list-item (i.e. each masonry item)
         */
        allItems.each(function (index) {
            ...
        });
    };

    $(window).on("load", function() {

        /* Resize all the grid items on the load and resize events */
        $(window).bind("load resize", function(e) {
           resizeAllMasonryItems( ".brick-inner" );
        });

        resizeAllMasonryItems(".brick-inner" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function name is `resizeAllMansonryItems` while you call it as `resizeAllMasonryItems`. 
There's one `s` in the middle of it: resizeAllMan**s**onryItems.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was soooo blind.

Answer (score 0):

Its a typo please review your function declaration name is change from your function call name